# Why is bootstrap changing a col-md div to 100% width @max-width:991?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using bootstrap so it would place my divs nicely next to eachother but whenever I resize my window to 991px width it makes these divs 100% width ...

code :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <img src="path..."  style="width: 100%; height: auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

picture (after resizing to 991px width):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first, meaning everything is handled as if it's on a small device unless you say otherwise. To change the breakpoint of your columns, use a smaller prefix:

```
col-xs-2
```

or

```
col-sm-2
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Also, instead of inline styles on your images (yuck), use Bootstrap's responsive image class:

```
class="img-responsive"
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: the inline styles were just for demonstration :) , and thanks a lot !!